# SQL Server - Exec sql statement across all database in all instances

Tags: sql, t-sql, dynamic, exec, instances

While ago I asked a question about how to execute dynamic SQL statement across all database in a specific instances. The answer was to use `sp_MSForEachDB`.

Now, I am facing another issue and need to executed the statement across all database in all instances that I have.

We have a vb script that is doing this, but I hope for a tsql solution.

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [SQL Multi script](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-multi-script/) from Red Gate. You can select all your databases and execute your sql in all of them and save the selection as a preset so you can use it again and again. You can also have multiple of these sets.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up [multi-server administration](http://www.yaldex.com/sql_server_tutorial_3/ch08lev1sec5.html) that pushes a job using `sp_MSForEachDB` to all the servers you control.

I documented a list of [multi-server requirements](http://www.mssqlforum.com/threads/multi-server-jobs-requirements.52/) on my site mssqlforum in case you want to set up multi-server administration.

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for sample solutions - that means without creating or setting additional settings. Only for select statement that I could executed.

Comment: Well, the adding of sp_MSForEachDB woudl do that, but it wouldn't work across servers. I doubt you'd find a way to get that done without having to touch some form of configuration (i.e. linked servers)